# How to fetch next page from REST API responses

Tags: python, pagination, linkedin-api

EDIT - Here is the 1st object/record in the response. I get a total of 20 records, including this:
Note: The response has been parsed to remove unicode i.e. u' and has ' replaced by " to make this into a valid json.

```
{
    "jobs": {
        "_total": 1811,
        "_count": 20,
        "_start": 0,
        "values": [{
            "siteJobUrl": "xxx",
            "company": {
                "id": 21836,
                "name": "CyberCoders"
            },
            "postingDate": {
                "year": 2013,
                "day": 10,
                "month": 6
            },
            "descriptionSnippet": "Software Engineer- Hadoop, HDFS, HBaseWe are a well known consumer product development company and we are looking to add a Hadoop Engineer to our Engineering team.  You will be working with the latest and greatest technologies to design, develop, and implement connectivity products that allow efficient exchange of data between our core database engine and the Hadoop ecosystem.What you need for thi",
            "expirationDate": {
                "year": 2013,
                "day": 10,
                "month": 7
            },
            "position": {
                "industries": {
                    "_total": 1,
                    "values": [{
                        "code": "4",
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "Computer Software"
                    }]
                },
                "title": "Software Engineer- Hadoop, HDFS, HBase",
                "experienceLevel": {
                    "code": "2",
                    "name": "Entry level"
                },
                "location": {
                    "country": {
                        "code": "us"
                    },
                    "name": "Greater Pittsburgh Area"
                },
                "jobFunctions": {
                    "_total": 1,
                    "values": [{
                        "code": "it",
                        "name": "Information Technology"
                    }]
                },
                "jobType": {
                    "code": "F",
                    "name": "Full-time"
                }
            },
            "customerJobCode": "CCW-ssehadooppaccw",
            "locationDescription": "Pittsburgh, PA",
            "jobPoster": {
                "headline": "Senior Executive Technical Recruiter at CyberCoders (949)885-5121 chelsea.whalen@cybercoders.com",
                "lastName": "W.",
                "id": "y2zfe5j76F",
                "firstName": "Chelsea"
            },
            "id": 6007298
        },
```

---

I am trying to use the below python library to make a job search api call to the linkedin REST API.

https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin/

I can access 1st page output just fine. But when I increment the start to point to next page, I still get the same response. What am I missing here?

Here is my code snippet:

```
authentication = LinkedInAuthentication(API_KEY, API_SECRET, RETURN_URL,
                                        PERMISSIONS.enums.values())
.......
application = LinkedInApplication(authentication)
........

# This is my request
response = application.search_job(
            selectors=[{'jobs':
                        ['id',
                         'customer-job-code',
                         'posting-date','expiration-date',
                         {'company':['id','name']},
                         {'position':['title',
                                      'location',
                                      'job-functions.',
                                      'industries',
                                      'job-type',
                                      'experience-level']},
                         'skills-and-experience',
                         'description-snippet',
                         'salary',
                         {'job-poster':['id',
                                        'first-name',
                                        'last-name',
                                        'headline']},
                         'referral-bonus',
                         'site-job-url',
                         'location-description']}],
            params={'keywords': 'hadoop','count': 20},
            headers={'start':20})
```

I had posted the query on linkedin developer forum too - http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/new-python-client-oauth-20
But got no response. I am new to python which is making it further difficult for me.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: that is your request ? Can you post the response ?

Comment: I couldn't add the link in site_url, Stackoverflow stops me from doing that. Hence changed it to xxx.

Comment: what is the vale you are setting to `start` for getting page 2 ?

Comment: AFAIK start = 20 should be used. I have tried both 20 and 21. Makes no difference. Its as though the setting is being ignored.

Comment: yes that makes sense, I'm still uncertain about what to include as parameters when passing `start` I can't find it in the docs https://developers.linkedin.com/documents/job-search-api

Comment: wait, why are you passing `start` in 'headers', it should be included as params.

Comment: Thats what I tried first. The script threw 'invalid argument' error, as mentioned here - http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/new-python-client-oauth-20.But to my surprise, I tried the same today and I see it work fine.

Comment: Thats what I tried first. The script threw 'invalid argument' error, as mentioned here - http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/new-python-client-oauth-20. But to my surprise, I tried the same today and I see it work fine. Not sure what is different. This is embarassing. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Gald to know it's working now.